# Bootbox prompt to get text content for jointJS element

Tags: javascript, bootbox, jointjs

I'm trying to add a new rectangle-element to a JointJS-diagram by doing a doubleclick on the working space. To define the text, which should be in this rectangle I tried to use bootbox.prompt.

But if I do the doubleclick, the bootbox is not on the fullscreen, but inside of the SVG - which is of course completely wrong. What am I doing wrong?

```
paper.on({
    'blank:pointerdblclick': function(evt, x, y) {
        bootbox.prompt("Text", function(text) {                
            if (result === null) {                                             
                Example.show("Prompt dismissed");                              
            } 
            else {*/
                var text = 'Some text';

                var rect = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
                    position: { x: x, y: y },
                    size: { width: 100, height: 80 },
                    attrs: { 
                        rect: { fill: '#ffffff', stroke: '#000000' }, 
                        text: { text: text, fill: '#000000' } 
                    }
                });

                graph.addCell(rect);
            }
        });
    }
});
```